# How to customize Nihilo.css?

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dijit.layout

One of the available themes in Dijit  is Nihilo.  I am using dijit/layout/.. for displaying  some charts and graphs . I want to change some of the styles being used. Can any one tell me how to customize Nihilo.css and use the customized version?

Answer (score 0):

Don't change nihilo.css, create another CSS file and put the link tag for the second file after the link tag for nihilo.css.

This way, if you upgrade Dojo, you will not have to merge your changes back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize nihilo, I would suggest to have a look at this official guide [Customizing a Theme](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html).

Basically the idea is to build your theme, based on nihilo leaving the original nihilo untouched,.